# Automate Posting Google Alerts to Yammer

Tags: yammer

Whats the best way to incorporate Google Alerts into Yammer? I've tried setting up an Exchange rule to auto forward the Google Alert emails to the Yammer group's email address, but that isn't working. When I manually forward the Google Alert emails to the group, that works, but they look awful. Does anyone have tips for a smooth integration of Google Alerts into a Yammer Group?

Answer (score 0):

I set Google Alerts to output to an RSS feed.  I then used [this IFTTT recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/89591-share-all-your-feeds-and-rss-to-yammer) to import that RSS feed into the intended Yammer group.  It works perfectly!